# I'm trying to get an entity field through a copied entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 entities: a singer and an album. Singer has several albums. I copied the essence of the singer and can get his ID and name, but I can't get a list of his albums. 
I have this exeption

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Entity.SingerEntity.albums, could not initialize proxy - no Session

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"singer\"")
public class SingerEntity {
    @Id
    private int singer_id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "singer_id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AlbumEntity> albums;

    public List<AlbumEntity> getAlbums() {
        return albums;
    }

    public void setAlbums(List<AlbumEntity> albums) {
        this.albums = albums;
    }

@Entity
@Table(name = "album")
public class AlbumEntity {
    @Id
    private int album_id;
    private String album_title;
    private String genre;
    private int singer_id;
```

main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SingerDAO sDAO = new SingerDAO();
    AlbumDAO aDAO = new AlbumDAO();

    SingerEntity s1 = new SingerEntity(1, "Singer");
    sDAO.insert(s1);

    AlbumEntity a1 = new AlbumEntity(1, "a1", "g1", s1);
    AlbumEntity a2 = new AlbumEntity(2, "a2", "g1", s1);
    AlbumEntity a3 = new AlbumEntity(3, "a3", "g2", s1);
    AlbumEntity a4 = new AlbumEntity(4, "a4", "g2", s1);

    aDAO.insert(a1);
    aDAO.insert(a2);
    aDAO.insert(a3);
    aDAO.insert(a4);

    s1 = sDAO.findById(1);
    System.out.println(s1.getId() + " , " + s1.getName());

    List<AlbumEntity> albums = s1.getAlbums();
    System.out.println(albums.get(0).getAlbum_title());
}
```

class SingerDAO:

```
public class SingerDAO {

public SingerEntity findById(int id) {
    Session session = null;
    SingerEntity singer = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        singer = (SingerEntity) session.get(SingerEntity.class, id);
        Hibernate.initialize(singer);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()){
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return singer;
}
public void select(){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query= session.createQuery("from SingerEntity");
    List<SingerEntity> list = query.list();
    for (SingerEntity s:list) {
        System.out.println(s.getName());
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}

public void insert(SingerEntity singerEntity){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(singerEntity);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}

public void update(SingerEntity sE){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.update(sE);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}

public void delete(SingerEntity sE){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(sE);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all map OneToMany bidirectional relation correctly. You should have

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "singer")
public class SingerEntity {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "singer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AlbumEntity> albums;
    ...
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "album")
public class AlbumEntity {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "singer_id)
    private SingerEntity singer;
    ....
}
```

If you want to add album to entity better to use custom method on Singer entity to keep references correct like:

```
public void addAlbum(AlbumEntity a) {
    albums.add(a);
    a.setSinger(this);
}
```

After that you can save albums just persisting singer as you have Cascade option.

Then as OneToMany relation collection is lazy by default you should load it in the same transaction where you get SingerEntity. So SingerEntity will be attached to Hibernate session. You can use Spring @Transactional annotation on your method for example.

I don't see your DAOs code but main can look:

```
SingerDAO sDAO = new SingerDAO();
AlbumDAO aDAO = new AlbumDAO();

SingerEntity s1 = new SingerEntity(1,"Singer");
s1.addAlbum(new AlbumEntity(1,"a1","g1",1)); 
s1.addAlbum(new AlbumEntity(2,"a2","g2",1)); 
s1.addAlbum(new AlbumEntity(3,"a3","g3",1)); 
s1.addAlbum(new AlbumEntity(4,"a4","g4",1)); 
sDAO.insert(s1);
```

Change findById to use one transaction for lazy loading:

```
public SingerEntity findById(int id) {
    Session session = null;
    SingerEntity singer = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        //start transaction
        singer = (SingerEntity) session.get(SingerEntity.class, id);
        Hibernate.initialize(singer);
        //end transaction 
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()){
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return singer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not quite understand what you mean. Could you write the code for the method main?

Comment: All I need is to display the names of all the artist's albums in the console.

Comment: I get this exeption:"Repeated column in mapping for entity: Entity.AlbumEntity column: singer_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")"

Comment: You can't have private int singer_id; and private SingerEntity singer; in one entity. You should remove int singer_id, exception will be gone.

Comment: I can not delete singer_id because this is the primary key of the entity

Comment: I am talking about Album entity

Comment: Again stops at the line " System.out.println(albums.get(0).getAlbum_title());" with Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Entity.SingerEntity.albums, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: I can't see your daos code, so I can only guess. In normal scenario you would load your singler/albums info in another method. Then you should have SingerDAO method getByID, so you take singer by id from EntityManager and then call singer.getAlbums().size() to load lazy collection. All this method should go in one transaction commonly done by @Transactional annotation

Comment: I added DAO class, please see.

Comment: the method works, I find the artist and I can get his fields, but why can not I get all his albums ??

Comment: Just add session.beginTransaction()/session.getTransaction().commit() to findById method.  session.get and Hibernate.initialize should go in one transaction. In other case after session.get you obtain detached object which can not load any lazy collections

Comment: I added "session.beginTransaction().commit();" Nothing changed. After which line should I insert this command?

Comment: Marked places for session.beginTransaction() and session.getTransaction().commit()  in edited answer

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Entity.SingerEntity.albums, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: Post you main() code, looks like you don't use your findById method properly

Comment: changed. Look please

Comment: You should call Hibernate.initialize(singer.getAlbums()), not Hibernate.initialize(singer)

Comment: Thank you very much. Happened. How can I put you a good rating ??

Comment: You are welcome, just check this answer as accepted)